# Is the .serverless folder needed for trouble-free execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

Will I need to push the .serverless folder to my repo and keep it updated to allow for a frictionless sls deployment or can I discard it at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .serverless folder will get re-generated every time you deploy and is just a build artifact, you can safely delete/ignore it.